# Number of comparisons made?

Tags: c, comparison-operators

I recently took an exam on C programming that provided these expressions:

```
int a = 3, b = 10, c = 4, d = 6;
```

1. <strike>`(c >= d) || (a > b)`</strike>

**correction: the first expression is:** `(c <= d) || (a > b)`

2. `(a <= b) && (c == d)`

and a question asking how many comparisons were made in each expression. I said there were three comparisons in each expression. In the first are great than or equal to, OR, and greater than. In the second is less than or equal to, AND, and equal to. But according to the grader, there's only one comparison in the first expression and two in the second.

Can anyone please explain why?

Are the integers relevant?

Comment: Why did you count the OR and AND operations as comparisons?

Comment: It is not possible to say without any information about the possible values of the variables. It can be `3` comparisons or `4`, it can even be `2`.

Comment: Actually values assigned to them are relevant. If a > b then comparison `c==d` won't be checked.

Comment: I'll add the values then.

Comment: @Michael Oops, I realize that mistake now.

Comment: The grader is wrong, according to the values you have added. There must be `2` comparison in first one. and `2` in the second one.

Comment: I'm recalling something my professor mentioned in lecture weeks ago. Is the term "partial evaluation" relevant in this context?

Comment: Are you certain you didn't make a mistake with the values or the expressions?  In particular, expression (1) as you've shown it will perform 2 comparisons, which differs from how it was graded.  Please check for an error in your post.

Comment: If you can fix your post, I can post a solution that explains this.  Specifically, I am expecting the first comparison to succeed, which you have as `c >= d`.  Please check this, and the values.

Comment: @TomKarzes correction: the first expression is (c <= d) || (a > b)

Comment: Ok thanks - just as I predicted.  That changes the number of comparisons from 2 to 1 for case (1).  I suggest editing your post to fix it.

Comment: @TomKarzes; I deleted my answer, but the answer was correct if you go through the edits.

Comment: Lolz, this can be the most number of edits (in questions and answers) in a minute. :D

Comment: Haha, sorry everyone. thanks for your patience

Comment: Ok, I posted an explanation of short-circuiting - see below.

Answer (score 4):

The integers are quite relevant to the context because of [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) operators `||` and `&&`.

For `||` the second comparison is never made if the first expression is true.

For `&&` the second comparison is never made if the first expression is false.

Also, the AND and OR operators themselves are not comparisons.

Answer (score 4):

Given the numbers are:

```
int a = 3, b = 10, c = 4 , d = 6;
```

For the first expression (after your update):

```
(c <= d) || (a > b)
```

variable `c` is smaller than `d` (4 is smaller 6), so that whole expression turns out true whatever the value of the second part is, so that's only 1 comparison.

For the second:

```
(a <= b) && (c == d)
```

Variable `a` is smaller than `b`, but the program has to check that other part too (in case `c` is not equal to `d` and they are  in fact different), so here there are also 2 comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

The point of this question was to determine whether you understood the concept of short-circuiting for `||` and `&&` in C.  These are logical connectives, not comparisons.

In your example, you are given:

```
int a = 3, b = 10, c = 4, d = 6;
```

You are then asked how many comparisons are performed for:

```
1.  (c <= d) || (a > b)
2.  (a <= b) && (c == d)
```

Both of these expressions contain two comparison operations, but that does not mean those comparisons will actually be performed.

In case (1), it first compares `c` vs. `d`, using `<=`.  The result of this is true (i.e. 1).  This is all it needs to determine that the result of the `||` operation will be true (i.e. 1), so it skips the second comparison of `(a > b)`, since it's not needed to obtain the final result.  This is called short-circuiting.

In case (2), it first compares `a` vs. `b` using `<=`.  The result of this is true (i.e. 1), so it proceeds to the second comparison of `(c == d)`.  The result of this is false (i.e. 0), so the final result is false (i.e. 0).

So for (1) it only needed to perform one comparison, but for (2) it needed to perform two comparisons.  If the values of the variables are changed, then the number of comparisons could change as well.